# Remove a member from multiple sets in Redis

Tags: redis

There are products and categories in my redis storage. I'm using categories sets to find products by specified category.

```
SADD category:1 product1 product2 product3 product4
SADD category:2 product2 product5
SADD category:5 product1 product7
```

Is there any way to remove a single product from all the categories except iterating over all of them? Eg some magic like this:

```
SREM category:* product2
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no magic command.

What you could do is use (yet another) Set to track the category Sets for each product. For example, in your example you'd have to do:

```
SADD product2:categories category:1 category:2
```

And then for each of that Set's members (`SMEMBERS` or `SSCAN` to get them), do an `SREM` for the product from that category.

Note that while this appears to be a perfect candidate for a Lua script, it is in fact not. This is because you'd be modifying keys (the categories' Sets) without explicitly providing their names via the KEYS input construct, a shunned-upon practice that will render said script non-cluster-compatible.